# Spring MVC 3 - Jackson - AjaxForm

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson, ajaxform

I have a Spring MVC annotation-driven project and it is working great. At this point, many of my forms are small and I have been prone to handle them using Ajax requests. I have been using this plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ to handle my Ajax requests, and it also has been working great. I have run into a problem though. I am using Jackson to serialize my @ResponseBody items into json. It has worked great, but I have run into my first form that needs to upload files. AjaxForm handles this on older browsers using the iframe submit trick, but warns that it is necessary to surround your response with `<textarea></textarea>` in order to be sure that all information arrives successfully. I have been looking around like crazy, and I see that I can make a Custom Serializer for my object, but I cannot think of how that would allow me to check if the request type is `XHR` and only then surround the response with the `<textarea></textarea>` tags. Any ideas?

Here is some of my code:

```
    public @ResponseBody
    JsonResponse setReferenceNumber(@ModelAttribute("referenceNumber") 
    @Valid ReferenceNumberBean referenceNumber, 
    BindingResult result, 
    HttpServletResponse response)
    {
      //Do some stuff
      //Theoretically here I would call upon some logic to surround the response?
      return jsonResponse;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE** -- I almost thought that I had fixed the problem, specifically by adding a new interceptor in Spring:

```
    <mvc:interceptors>
      <bean class="edge.portal.vendor.web.interceptor.MultipartAjaxInterceptor"></bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>
```

Then having the interceptor test to see if the X-Requested-with, then adding the tags if my javascript had flagged the call as Ajax but the headers didn't reflect this change, thus implying an iframe ajax post:

```
    @Component
    public class MultipartAjaxInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
    {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception
    {
    if(request.getParameter("isAjax") != null && request.getHeader("X-Requested-With") == null)
        response.getWriter().write("<textarea>");

    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception
       {
       if(request.getParameter("isAjax") != null && request.getHeader("X-Requested-With") == null)
           response.getWriter().write("</textarea>");
       }
    }
```

Now obviously the problem that I ran into is that you cannot call the getWriter or OutputStream of the response more than once, I feel like I am on the right track to solving this but do not know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a little late for an answer here, but I recently had a similar issue and I'd like to share my results. You were on the right track with the HandlerInterceptor, but you should have used the getOutputStream() method instead of the getWriter() method. According to the [Javadoc for ServletReponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream()):

```
getOutputStream

Throws:
IllegalStateException - if the getWriter method has been called on this response
```

Similarly, the getWriter method will throw IllegalStateException if getOutputStream has already been called, but each one can be multiple times as long as the other is never called. Jackson appears to use getOutputStream when writing the JSON data. So your code should work with the following modification:

```
@Component
public class MultipartAjaxInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
{
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if(request.getParameter("isAjax") != null && request.getHeader("X-Requested-With") == null)
            response.getOutputStream().write("<textarea>".getBytes(response.getCharacterEncoding()));

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
       if(request.getParameter("isAjax") != null && request.getHeader("X-Requested-With") == null)
           response.getOutputStream().write("</textarea>".getBytes(response.getCharacterEncoding()));
    }
}
```

It may also be helpful to change the response's content type by using the setContentType method in postHandle if the response was originally sent as "application/json".

Answer (score 1):

Let me post, how I solved this problem (Which I don't know, is proper or not)
.
I use Dojo in my front-end and Dojo uses `dojo.io.iframe.send` for file upload. The JS function which handle form post as follow. (Look at "`handleAs`" property I set is as '`json`')

```
function ioIframeGetJson(){
    var td = dojo.io.iframe.send({
        url: "${pageContext. request. contextPath}/switch/add",
        form: "frmSwitchTypeAdd",
        method: "post",
        preventCache: true, 
        handleAs: "json",
         load: function(response, ioArgs){
                clearSwitchTypeForm();
            },

            error: function(response, ioArgs){
            }
    });
}
```

In my case, the controller method which handles the form submit, which also includes uploaded file is as below, (Look I have kept my return type to String)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String add(HttpServletRequest request) {
        . . . . .
        //I call the toString method of the model I want to return in Response
        return fromModel(switchType).toString();
}
```

And the `toString()` method is coded as below, I make Json string surrounded by `<textarea>`

```
public String toString() {
        return "<textarea>{name:'" + name + "', code:'" + code
                + "', className:'" + className + "', dynamic:" + dynamic+"}</textarea>";
    }
```

Comment: I may end up having to do that, I was hoping that I would still be able to use the JsonSerializer since it's so helpful, but it appears that may not be an option.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the answer I arrived at, it is similar to Ravi's answer, but seemed a little better for my setup. First thing was to change my `@ResponseBody`'s to be Strings. This was done assuming that I would be manually surrounding the responses with `<textarea />` tags. I then made a new class called `JsonResponseSerializer` which looked as follows:

```
public class JsonResponseSerializer
{
private HttpServletRequest request;

public JsonResponseSerializer(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    this.request = request;
}

public String serialize(JsonResponse jsonResponse) throws IOException
  {
    String response = "";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    response = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonResponse);

    if(request.getParameter("isAjax") != null && request.getHeader("X-Requested-With") == null)
    {
        response = "<textarea>" + response + "</textarea>";
    }

    return response;
  }
}
```

Then I changed the return statements of my response's to this:

```
    return new JsonResponseSerializer(request).serialize(jsonResponse);
```

Essentially, I made a utility method that has the ServletRequest injected then simply asks Jackson to serialize the object, then surrounds it with the `<textarea />` if necessary.